# Geometric picture behind tilting sheaves

Tags: perverse-sheaves, intuition, tilting

I am trying to read ["Tilting exercises"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301098) and have trouble to see any geometric pictures behind the formulas.

So my questions are, how to think about tilting perverse sheaves?

Are they just formal gadgets or have they a "geometric meaning"? Can one draw a pictiure of a tilting sheaf? etc.

A closely related question is the connection between tilting sheaves and glueing. Let $U$ be an open subset of an algebraic variety $X$ and $i:Z\rightarrow X$ its complement. 
Let $M$ be a perverse sheaf on $U$ with tilting extension $M^{tilt}$ on $X$. Define

$\Psi:=i^! M^{tilt}$ and $\Psi':=i^* M^{tilt}$ and $\tau: \Psi\rightarrow \Psi' $ the map induced from $i_* i^! \rightarrow id \rightarrow i_* i^*$

Then BBM show (Prop 1.2) that the category of extensions of of $M$ to $X$ is equivalent to the category of diagrams $\Psi \rightarrow \Phi \rightarrow \Psi'$ such that the composition equals $\mathcal \tau$.

How should one think of $\Psi$ and $\Psi'$? What would be a good name for $\Psi$ and $\Psi'$? What is the geometric picture behind this glueing construction?

Comment: I'm not sure about a geometric picture. It might be helpful to play with tiliting objects in the category O and the maximal extension from Beilinson's gluing paper.

Comment: Tilting modules (in the derived categories of quiver representations) can sometimes be displayed using the Auslander-Reiten quiver. This is the case in particular for coeherent sheaves on P¹. See for examples images at the end of http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~keller/publ/dct.pdf